# Hartshorne Exercise II.3.17 Noetherian Induction

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm confused by the Noetherian Induction exercise in Hartshorne.

> Let $X$ be a Noetherian topological space, and let $\mathscr{P}$ be a property of closed subsets of $X$. Assume that for any closed subset $Y$ of $X$, if $\mathscr{P}$ holds for every proper closed subset of $Y$, then $\mathscr{P}$ holds for $Y$. (In particular, $\mathscr{P}$ must hold for the empty set.) Then $\mathscr{P}$ holds for $X$.

Using Zorn's Lemma, we can say that the set $\Sigma$ of closed subsets of $Y$ where $\mathscr{P}$ holds has a maximal element, but how do we know that the maximal element is $X$? I want to say that we can take the union of all closed subsets in $\Sigma$ and that should be $X$ but why is the union of all closed subsets in $\Sigma$ equal to $X$?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to exchange $Y$ by $X$ in your question. For $Y$ already know this by assumption.

Comment: For the empty set we know, that $\mathscr{P}$ hold for every proper subset, because there are no proper subsets. Thus $\mathscr{P}$ holds for the empty set as well, by assumption.

Comment: In my Hartshorne's book this is Exercise II.3.16 .. I'm not sure if I have to correct this post. Are there multiple versions of this book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the set $S$ of closed subsets that do *not* satisfy $\mathscr{P}$.

Assume that $S$ is not empty. Then you can find an infinite descending chain in $S$ as follows:

> for any closed subset $Y$ of $X$, if $\mathscr{P}$ holds for every
>   proper closed subset of $Y$, then $\mathscr{P}$ holds for $Y$

can be rewritten by contrapositive

> for any element $Y$ of $S$, there is a proper closed subset of $Y$ that also lies in $S$

But this contradicts $X$ being Noetherian.

Comment: Which part of definition of not satisfying $\mathscr{P}$ gives us this infinite descending chain in $S$?

Comment: @nekodesu I edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense now!

Comment: @nekodesu You're welcome!